# How to Change Debug Color(s) of Ecto

Tags: elixir, ecto

I'm trying to get Ecto to print its default SQL debug statements but instead of red for DELETE, some other color as red makes other devs think it looks like an error.

I can't find an example of this anywhere. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, this does not seem to be possible because the color is [hardcoded in *Ecto*](https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto_sql/blob/0464becc640dcb9b830b56cca5affa060d893704/lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex#L934).

Comment: According to this it can be overridden but I haven't seen an example of how - https://github.com/elixir-ecto/ecto/issues/2566

Comment: by providing your own log callback in the repository configuration, as it is clearly stated in the answer.

Comment: Do you have a link to such an example? I don't know what that is.